# SAML 2.0 Multiple md:NameIDFormat tag in service provider metadata

Tags: service, metadata, saml, provider

I was looking at some SAML 2.0 service provider metadata examples and came across a metadata file that had multiple NameIDFormat tags. Now most other examples I saw had just one so does this snippet indicate that the SP would accept NameID in SAML 1.1 as well as SAML 2.0 formats and can accept transient as well as persistent nameIDs in case of SAML 2.0 responses?

```
<md:NameIDFormat>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:emailAddress</md:NameIDFormat>
<md:NameIDFormat>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:transient</md:NameIDFormat>
<md:NameIDFormat>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:persistent</md:NameIDFormat>
<md:NameIDFormat>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:unspecified</md:NameIDFormat>
<md:NameIDFormat>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:X509SubjectName</md:NameIDFormat>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just so that others who are looking for an answer to this question know - I was able to confirm that my understanding is correct. SP can advertise support for multiple NameID formats that it can support using multiple tags in the SP metadata. However, its upto the IdP to honor this and send the NameID in one of the supported formats or completely ignore it and send it in a format not supported by the SP. In that case however the SP will not be able to parse the NameID value and will fail.